# Gradle multi-module project

Tags: java, gradle

Sorry, I'm new with gradle, but already spent a lot of time for configuring my project.

I have following gradle project structure (`gradle projects`):

```
Root project 'app'
+--- Project ':analytics'
|    +--- Project ':analytics:lambda-1'
|    |    \--- Project ':analytics:lambda-1:api'
|    \--- Project ':analytics:lambda-2'
|         \--- Project ':analytics:lambda-2:api'
\--- Project ':back'
```

Root `settings.gradle` includes all modules:

```
include 'back'
include 'analytics'

include 'analytics:lambda-1'
include 'analytics:lambda-1:api'
include 'analytics:lambda-2'
include 'analytics:lambda-2:api'
```

What I want to achieve is that `:back` to be depends on both `:analytics:lambda-1:api` and `:analytics:lambda-2:api`

But unfortunately, I having compilation error and only one of those (first one -- `analytics:lambda-1:api`) of `compile project` actually included into build path.

```
project(':back') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':analytics:lambda-1:api')
        compile project(':analytics:lambda-2:api')
    }
}
```

Gradle version: `Gradle 3.3`

Could anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: Why do you need those evaluationDependsOn?

Comment: Ok, you're right. This is not necessary.